# Generate model in Rails using user_id:integer vs user:references

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm confused on how to generate a model that belongs_to another model. My book uses this syntax to associate Micropost with User:

```
rails generate model Micropost user_id:integer
```

but https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration says to do it like this:

```
rails generate model Micropost user:references
```

The migrations generated by these 2 are different. Also, for the former, how does rails know that `user_id` is a foreign key referencing `user`? Thanks!

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Both will generate the same columns when you run the migration.  In rails console, you can see that this is the case:

```
:001 > Micropost
=> Micropost(id: integer, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

The second command adds a `belongs_to :user` relationship in your Micropost model whereas the first does not.  When this relationship is specified, ActiveRecord will assume that the foreign key is kept in the `user_id` column and it will use a model named `User` to instantiate the specific user.

The second command also adds an index on the new `user_id` column.

Comment: Is it possible to generate a model with references of two tables

Comment: Note that it does not add a has_many association on the other model (user), which you may want to add as well.

Comment: I think using `:references` will create an index on the foreign key, whereas manually making the column will not?

Answer (score 62):

> how does rails know that `user_id` is a foreign key referencing `user`?

Rails itself does not know that `user_id` is a foreign key referencing `user`. In the first command `rails generate model Micropost user_id:integer` it only adds a column `user_id` however rails does not know the use of the col. You need to manually put the line in the `Micropost` model

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
end
```

the keywords `belongs_to` and `has_many` determine the relationship between these models and declare `user_id` as a foreign key to `User` model.

The later command `rails generate model Micropost user:references` adds the line `belongs_to :user` in the `Micropost` model and hereby declares as a foreign key.

**FYI**
Declaring the foreign keys using the former method only lets the Rails know about the relationship the models/tables have. The database is unknown about the relationship. Therefore when you generate the EER Diagrams using software like `MySql Workbench` you find that there is no relationship threads drawn between the models. Like in the following pic 
[image]

However, if you use the later method you find that you migration file looks like:

```
def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :microposts, :users
```

Now the foreign key is set at the database level. and you can generate proper `EER` diagrams.
[image]

Comment: It seems that latest Rails generator replaced the `add_foreign_key` action with an option `foreign_key: true` to the `t.references` line, which implies `index: true`. So it is now `t.references :user, foreign_key: true`. There is currently no documentation for the `foreign_key` option available, so this is only my assumption.

Comment: Oh, the [`add_reference` action](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) has a `:foreign_key` option which *add an appropriate foreign key constraint*. I guess this option would do the same when creating table.

Comment: How do you export your ruby db to workbench? could you maybe answer this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982921/exporting-a-ruby-on-rails-sql-db-to-mysql-workbench

Comment: Does having `add_foreign_key :microposts, :users ` make any difference for Rails?

Answer (score 17):

For the former, convention over configuration. Rails default when you reference another table with

```
 belongs_to :something
```

is to look for `something_id`.

`references`, or `belongs_to` is actually newer way of writing the former with few quirks.

Important is to remember that it will not create foreign keys for you. In order to do that, you need to set it up explicitly using either:

```
t.references :something, foreign_key: true
t.belongs_to :something_else, foreign_key: true
```

or (note the plural):

```
add_foreign_key :table_name, :somethings
add_foreign_key :table_name, :something_elses`
```

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by saying that references will not create foreign keys for you. How is it different from first command using user_id:integer directly?

Comment: It isn't, except in case you are using `:polymorphic` option (which IMHO, for most cases, is not a good idea). If you want to utilize foreign keys in ActiveRecord, use [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner).

Comment: @Krule Now `add_foreign_key` has made it into ActiveRecord.