# How to create an association on a different column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user model:

```
users
-id
-external_id

sales
-id
-external_id
```

So my models with associations looks like:

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sales
end
```

How can I link the associations through the column 'external_id' ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use foreign_key here.

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :external_id
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sales, foreign_key: :external_id
end
```

Comment: If this is what the OP is looking for, then here is a similar question with more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/904452/2437278

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean you want the column name to be `external_id`or if you just are wondering how to get an external id (foreign key). I'm going to assume the latter since this is how a relational db is usually set up.
When you make a model, you would do it like this, for example:

`rails g model user email:string password:string`

`rails g model sale user:references amount:decimal`

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862031/2437278)

That would create tables that look like this:

```
Users
email: string
password: string

Sales
user_id: integer
amount: decimal
```

Where `user_id` is the foreign key to the user associated with that sale since a user has many sales and a sale belongs to a user.

Remember: the id of the 1 goes on the many.